# How can this CDF be decreasing? (power-law)

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function, networks, power-law, social-network

I am reading the [first vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/poweRlaw/vignettes/a_introduction.pdf) of the powerRlaw R package.

It uses the `moby` dataset, which is an array of word frequency. Each element is a word, and the value if the frequency of that word in the Moby Dick novel.

At page 5 there is a plot of the CDF for this dataset:

[image]

There is a similar plot in the article

> Newman, M. E. J. (2005). Power laws, Pareto distributions and Zipf’s law. Contemporary Physics, 46(5), 323–351. https://doi.org/10.1080/00107510500052444

at page 6:

[image]

Now Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) that CDF are increasing functions, starts at 0 and end up at 1.

How can this CDF be decreasing?

Comment: The first figure that you have posted, y axis is incorrect. It should be called CCDF (complementary cumulative distribution function) or survival function.

Comment: The $y$-axis scale on the second chart is not a probability (it exceeds $1$) - in fact it is the number of distinct words which appear at least $x$ times, so goes up to $18855$ on the left hand side

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The vignette by [Gillespie (2020)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/poweRlaw/vignettes/a_introduction.pdf) cites [Clauset et al (2009)](http://tuvalu.santafe.edu/%7Eaaronc/courses/5352/readings/Clauset_Shalizi_Newman_09_PowerlawDistributionsInEmpiricalData.pdf) as another source of the figure.  Reading that latter paper, it looks like they are actually plotting the *complementary* CDF (better known as the survival function), which is $P(x) = 1-F(x) = \mathbb{P}(X>x)$.  This latter function is of course non-*increasing* rather than non-decreasing.  Both papers are sloppy in their references to this function (they really shouldn't call it the CDF), but that appears to be their intention.